# RTNETLINK answers: Operation not supported

Tags: networking, kernel-modules

I'm getting some errors in my xen logs and googling has turned up that it's related to iproute2.

I found through google that the key is to enable CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y in my kernel config.  It turns out, that it is.  This link provided more clues.

https://superuser.com/questions/232807/iproute2-not-functioning-rtnetlink-answers-operation-not-supported

However, all of these options are enabled in my running kernel, but not as statically compiled modules but as Linux loadable kernel modules.

I'm guessing I just need to add the appropriate module names to /etc/modules

This is what I have in my running kernel config

```
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=m 
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_QUEUE=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK_LOG=m 
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=m 
CONFIG_SCSI_NETLINK=y 
CONFIG_IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER=y 
CONFIG_NET_SCH_INGRESS=m 
CONFIG_NET_SCHED=y 
IP_MULTIPLE_TABLES=y 
NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_MARK=m
```

What do I need to add to /etc/modules to get this working properly?

Comment: What command triggers the error message? What is the exact error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those `NETFILTER_*` configuration options control modules for iptables. To get more information about such an configuration option, you can look it up on a site like http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/IP_ADVANCED_ROUTER.html. In this case, there is no loadable module, the only valid options are "Y" and "N".

For [CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NETFILTER_NETLINK.html), the module name is `nfnetlink`:

```
The configuration item CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK:

    prompt:
    type: tristate
    depends on: (none)
    defined in net/netfilter/Kconfig
    found in Linux kernels: 2.6.25–2.6.39, 3.0–3.2, 3.3-rc+HEAD
    modules built: nfnetlink
```