# multiple NICs under ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, routing, nic, netplan

How to translate what we had to do to have 2 independent stream of traffic on 2 or more NIC interfaces with the new netplan.io + systemd-networkd?

```
auto ens2
iface ens2 inet static
address 192.168.5.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.5.1
dns-nameservers 1.1.1.1

auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
address 192.168.3.15
netmask 255.255.255.0


up ip route add default table 102 dev ens3 via 192.168.3.1
up ip rule add from 192.168.3.0/24 lookup 102
down ip rule del from 192.168.3.0/24
down ip route del default table 102 via 192.168.3.1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses: [192.168.3.15/24]
      dhcp4: no 
      routes:
       - to: 0.0.0.0/0
         via: 192.168.3.1
         metric: 100
         table: 101
      routing-policy:
       - from: 192.168.3.0/24
         table: 101
    ens2:
      addresses: [192.168.5.100/24]
      dhcp4: no
      gateway4: 192.168.5.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [1.1.1.1]
```

This has been confirmed by 'cyphermox' on IRC, lead developer on netplan.io.
Check with `ip route` and `ip rule` if `systemd` has created everything needed and if not restart it -> `sudo service systemd-networkd restart`