# 2 network interfaces with different gateways

Tags: networking, server

I followed this answer: [how to configure 2 network interfaces with different gateways](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868942/how-to-configure-2-network-interfaces-with-different-gateways?answertab=votes#tab-top)

No errors when setting up.

ifconfig:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.178.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 fe80::21d:9ff:fe6b:ca86  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1d:09:6b:ca:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2785  bytes 224135 (218.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 977  bytes 116595 (113.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.37  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::21d:9ff:fe6b:ca88  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1d:09:6b:ca:88  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

network interfaces:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 192.168.178.22
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.178.1

allow-hotplug eno2
iface eno2 inet static
address 192.168.1.37
netmask 255.255.255.0
post-up ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno2 src 192.168.1.37 table rt2
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.37 dev eno2 table rt2
post-up ip rule add from 192.168.1.37/32 table rt2
post-up ip rule add to 192.168.1.37/32 table rt2
```

rt_tables:

```
#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
1 rt2
```

ping -I eno1... ok
ping -I eno2... 100% packet loss. I can ping another computer and back to server from that computer. Also I can ping modem. Any external ping like google doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I did wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Does a ping to 8.8.8.8 get a reply? The question being, is it just DNS that isn't working?

Comment: No it does not. ping -I eno2 8.8.8.8 ... 4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to have 2 default gateways (DGW).  You should only have one DGW and routing tables for the other NIC.

The mistake is here:

```
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.37 dev eno2 table rt2
```

So just remove that line and all 192.168.1.0 will be routed to that NIC

If you want to persist in your erroneous ways, you can still add a second default gateway (*I repeat: **it's a bad idea***) and then the line should¹ read:

```
post-up ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev eno2 table rt2
```

<sub>**Note 1:** *should very probably*  as it depends on your network configuration</sub>